# simple program with SPSS syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I start working with spss 22. Is their any option to use spss syntax like following:

```
i as int
l as int

cout<<i+l
```

or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `cout<<i+1` and why you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Syntax. You have to use File>New>Script in older versions and Python in newer